# Calling of postConstruct and preDestroy methods of beans in Quarkus

Tags: cdi, quarkus

Here is a brief overview of a problem:

I want to call bean lifecycle methods without restarting an application.
I need to call interceptor methods (PostConstruct and PreDestroy) of superclasses during reloading of beans in Quarkus and CDI/Weld.

For example, I have end-point for that: /reload - it fires bean reload where I need to go through all beans annotated with my custom annotation and call(if such an annotation presents) posconstr and predestr annotations, BUT I want to preserve bean call order (if bean extends superclass that has such lifecycle callback, then I want to call it first).

What I did to fix it: I used a reflection to call them. But I think it is a kind of dirty fix and hope there should be a more wise solution. There is a solution using CDI:

```java
beanManager.getInjectionTargetFactory(
            beanManager.createAnnotatedType(instance.getClass())).createInjectionTarget(
            bean).postConstruct(instance)
```

CDI has getInjectionTargetFactory in beanManager, Quarkus does not support this method. 
 It works but I search solution using Quarkus methods.

**Does Quarkus have a possibility to call postConstruct and preDestroy methods of all beans without restarting an application?**

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regular CDI annotations `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` on your beans. Quarkus will honor them.

For example:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBean {
    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        // do something
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void destroy() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Be careful that they will be called at bean initialization and destruction time not application initialization and destruction time, for this there is specific event that you can listen on : https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#listening-for-startup-and-shutdown-events

Comment: I agree with you, but I need to call PostConstruct after first call of Postconstruct

Comment: _"I need to call PostConstruct after first call of Postconstruct"_ weird, why? But you always can call `init()` again. It *is* a method

Comment: @Kukeltje I need something like this: `createInjectionTarget(
            bean).postConstruct(instance)` but for Quarkus