# Initiating a service right after Quarks starts

Tags: quarkus

I need to write a piece of code that will run right after quarks is up and running.
Was wondering if such a thing is possible with Quarkus, I tried to do it with a Quarkus main but this only allows me to run the code prior to Quarkus starting.

What is the first module or class that is running when running the below command?

```
mvn compile quarkus:dev
```

Comment: try @PostConstruct example https://stackoverflow.com/a/60186920/175554

Comment: Is https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#listening-for-startup-and-shutdown-events what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to startup and shutdown events, this is [the quarkus guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#listening-for-startup-and-shutdown-events) that explains how to do it.

Just quoting this guide:

```java
package org.acme.lifecycle;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;

import io.quarkus.runtime.ShutdownEvent;
import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@ApplicationScoped
public class AppLifecycleBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("ListenerBean");

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {               
        LOGGER.info("The application is starting...");
    }

    void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent ev) {               
        LOGGER.info("The application is stopping...");
    }

}
```

Comment: Now I saw that this is the same answer that @geoand gave .